# Python - Manual - libary installation Failure on Windows with Spacy, Thinc and msgpack-numpy python 3.7

Tags: python, numpy

All, I am pursuing a path of manual installation of python libraries, one that unfortunately, I cannot deviate from and it has become challenging because some of the libraries are just not easily found from pypi.org.    This is a Windows 10 set up using Anaconda for `python 3.7`

My goal is to install SPACY and I have tried this version: `spacy-2.0.18-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

Which Requires Collecting `thinc<6.13.0,>=6.12.1 (from spacy==2.0.18)`

Now I can't seem to find `6.13.0`   But was able to find `6.12.1` also found `thinc-7.0.0`.

so I installed thinc-7.0.0 but spacy does not recognize that as `>= 6.12.1`  not sure if I am interpreting it correctly.

So instead I install `thinc-6.12.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

which fails because it is looking for.. `Collecting msgpack-numpy<0.4.4.0 (from thinc==6.12.0)`

However `msgpack-numpy<0.4.4.0`  seems undiscoverable.

I have found `msgpack_numpy-0.4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
I also Found `msgpack_numpy-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

of which neither will be accepted by `thinc-6.12.0 as valid`.

So have I chosen the wrong spacy version to start with for 3.7?

I tried this path in 3.6 and I think I was able to get it all to work, is the python 3.7 path just broken?

If someone knows the path and the location of the files to get spacy to work, that would be great.   Unfortunately, I cannot just issue pip commands at this time..

best regards

Comment: It is strange that I seem to be stuck by the requirement for msgpack_numpy 0.4.4.0 because when I check the history on https://pypi.org/project/msgpack-numpy/#history  that version has not ever been published there?    only 0.4.4  0.4.4.1 and 0.4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I figured out the simple mistake I was making...
Collecting msgpack-numpy<0.4.4.0 (from thinc==6.12.0)    Does not mean, I need 0.4.4.0  it means I need a package less than 0.4.4.0.

So I found msgpack_numpy-0.4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

It is confusing to list packages as a less than or equal requirement that do not actually exist.

I eventually was able to install spacy after many tries of different combinations of thinc, regex, spacy

regex==2018.01.10
msgpack-numpy 0.4.3.2
thinc-6.12.1
Successfully installed spacy-2.0.18